# Use Win7 + IE11, can not download some file from internal web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm not sure this is application problem or system setting, dose some one can help me to figure out what is wrong, and fix this problem.

two Web Server

```
Host Server: Windows 2008 R1 + IIS 7.5 + aspx, aspx.vb
Test Server: Windows 2008 standard + IIS 7 + aspx, aspx.vb
```

**Client:**

```
Win 7 + IE11 (upgrade from IE8)
```

all applications are same on each server.
download file use Excel 2003 to be template.

**Problem:**

> use Win7 + IE8 to generate download file, all is fine, both two server.
>   when use Win7 + IE11 to generate download file, on test server, all is fine, on Host server, can be generate but some file can not download, all can show "open","save", seems every things is ok, but click "open" or "save", some file can work, some file will show "can not be download", if click "retry", file can download, but all content will be replace by download web page.
>   Someone tell me this is IE11 security issue, ask me to check application, I'm curious, if is IE11 security issue, why this problem only happen on Host Server not on test server?

**report generate process**

```
Dim ObjExcel as New Excel.application
Dim ObjWB as Excel.Workbook = Nothing
Dim ObjWs as Excel.WorkSheet = Nothing
ObjExcel.Workbooks.open(filename)
ObjExcel.worksheets(name)
```

----begin insert data-----

```
ObjWB.SaveAs(Tempfile)
ObjExcel.quit()

Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.AddHeader("Contest-Disposition", "attachment")
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.WriteFile(Tempfile)
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
```

Thanks!

Can

Comment: Did you manually check the generated files on the "Host" server? Are they valid Excel files?

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, I will try to check those files, but when use IE8, everything is fine, why? and same action only happen on Host Server? Sorry! I'm just curious

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file to be downloaded, you should set the content type to "application/octet-stream". Also, it's "content-disposition", not "Contest-Disposting". You can use Response.TransmitFile for more efficiency. Finally, it might be a good idea to suggest a filename to the browser. So...

```
Dim filename As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & ".xls"
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & filename & """")
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.TransmitFile(Tempfile)
```

Comment: Sorry! type wrong, is "Contest-Disposition", and I will try your suggest. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a question, on Host Server has several ap use same way to generate downloadable file, some can download very well, but some will caused "can't download" error, can you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: You could look in the IIS log file to see if there is an error code associated with the failed download and then look up the meaning of that error code. You may also need to look in the Windows event logs.